# NodeJS Error: node.js:810 var cwd = process.cwd();

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodeJS and also new to StackOverflow...

I'm starting to develop my first SPA, using RequireJS to compile my sources into a "dist" folder. I had NodeJS running a basic script to run my server:

```
var connect = require('connect');
connect.createServer(
    connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8080);
```

Everything was working well, till I compile my src again. That replaced all the files served by my server, so I though I would restart Node. I Ctrl^C and from this moment, I can't get Node to start again. When I try to run:

```
olivier$ node server.js
```

I get this error:

```
node.js:810
    var cwd = process.cwd();
                  ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
    at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:810:23)
    at startup (node.js:58:13)
    at node.js:901:3
```

What's strange is that I get the same error just trying to start NodeJS, simply doing:

```
olivier$node
```

Anyone has an idea of what I can do beside uninstalling Node and reinstalling it ?

Answer (score 137):

I got this when trying to run the Node REPL from a directory I had already deleted (from another shell). Don't let this happen to you or you will be ashamed.

Comment: Me too! Thanks for being brave and come out about this ;)

Comment: directory was deleted!! I don't know why...! This solved my problem, thank you!!

Comment: Another red face here!

Comment: I dunno what happened exactly, but I was in a terminal on my external drive, disconnected the drive, reconnected it and got this error on my next `npm install`. Doing `cd ..` and `cd project-dir` corrected it.

Comment: I got this when created a directory in a git branch, switched to a different branch (without the new directory), and switched back. Like @StevenVachon said, `cd` up a level and back in fixes the problem.

Comment: I literally can't even.. SMH

Comment: I'm also wearing the cone of shame. :(

Comment: Double-fail...I was about to discount this question, because my cwd was my module directory, which couldn't have been deleted... Then I noticed that I was actually in the global *installation* directory of my module, and I had just run `npm install -g` *in there*, which both deleted that existing module directory and (of course) didn't install the new code I wanted, but only installed the code that was...already installed. +1 me if anyone else does this...please? Someone else?

Comment: I just couldn't stop laughing. This kind of thing hurts more than a heart break.

Comment: @sphtkr no problem: me :) 
Didn't notice that the Jenkins workspace was already removed by Jenkins...

Comment: another confession.

Comment: macOS, was in dir, deleted dir, recloned to same dir, still had to `cd` out and back to get the command to work. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: My smartness made me feel ashamed today :( ...lol.... Over-productivity create bugs jaja

Comment: It also happens if the folder was deleted but recreated with the exact same name.

Answer (score 21):

Could it be that RequireJS is also recreating the directory that contains your `server.js`?

Try and see if this works:

```
$ cd $PWD; node server.js
```

Although it seems useless to change the directory to the current directory, the rationale is that when a directory gets deleted while it's the current working directory of your shell, the shell is left in a dangling state because it's still 'attached' to the previously deleted directory. This also affects any processes that you start from that shell (like Node), and can yield confusing errors.

By executing `cd $PWD`, you make sure your shell gets 'reattached' to the newly created version of the directory, solving the dangling state.

Comment: Exactly! That was the problem! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: thanks - i don't know why but "cd $PWD" solved my (Grunt) issues, too.
Isn't "cd $PWD" a completly useless command? i mean obviously it isnt't but can anybody explain why?

Comment: @fbtb if your current directory gets deleted (for instance, when running a program that deletes it first and then creates it again), your shell is left in a dangling state (because it's still 'attached' to the previously deleted directory). By executing `cd $PWD`, you make sure your shell gets 'reattached' to the newly created version of the directory.

Comment: @robertklep you should really add your comment into your answer as it's much more relevant as a whole than just the RequireJS bit!

Answer (score 8):

use

```
cd .
```

is ok.

But the problem is in server

Comment: This worked for me as i was in `dist` folder, which was deleted and created again when i made new build. Doing `cd .` just worked

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue.

To Solve this issue enter below command :

```
cd ..
```

OR

```
Check your directory in Terminal/CMD. and Change it.
```

Actually this issue coming when you deleted your project folder form your PC and without change directory try to run any command of React-Native.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the folder in another terminal and save its the file,
Open the new terminal on folder structure, and run the file.

Folder structure was not available on the current terminal session. When you close it and re-open the terminal in your file directory, the structure will be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to close all the terminals and run below commands

```
sudo npm cache clean -f 

sudo npm install -g n
```

and voila: no more process.cwd problems

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of a problem when starting the app in cluster mode via pm2.

I did the following & it worked,
 * executed pm2 kill
 * Removed node_modules
 * npm install
 * start the application
Reference: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1244

Then it started to work as expected. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If we try to do any actions on an already deleted file from another shell then we'll face this issue.
Just restart the system it'll work normally ( It worked for me )